# No inittab.d directory found during boot log?

Tags: debian, devuan

After upgrading a non-systemd VM from Debian 11 Bullseye to Debian 12 Bookworm, I started seeing upon boot, the message:

```
init: No inittab.d directory found during boot log
```

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is only a warning, and not a blocking error. /sbin/init is checking whether /etc/inittab.d exists or not.

To get rid of of the warning message, run:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/inittab.d
```